# flutter A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle, dart

I have a problem running  my flutter app. ERORR : "Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']

Console:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ariel\AndroidStudioProjects\study_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\ariel\AndroidStudioProjects\study_app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
`
Please Can someone help me?

`

Comment: did you find answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Edit the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties in file: /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

Change zip package to gradle-6.5-all.zip

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```